# Javascript Error: "null or not an object"

Tags: javascript, null, undefined

I have a strange problem here:
http://jackyon.com.s146246.gridserver.com/thehappymonk/

I'm using the queryloader2 plugin and maximage2 plugin. It works fine on all modern browsers, but is showing the javascript error on IE8 or below. Even IE9 shows an error, but it still can normally run.

```
js error: 'a.Slide[...].content.length' is null or not an object.
```

When removing either plugin, the page runs without error.

million thanks guys! This problem already drive me crazy few days. Please help me! Thanks!!

Comment: What have you done to try and find the error?

Comment: I have done nothing, I just only include these two plugin and then it shows an error on ie8 or below. can you advise some solutions? thx!

Answer (score 1):

The error seems to be coming from jquery.maximage.min.js, the full version is here: https://github.com/akv2/MaxImage/blob/master/lib/js/jquery.maximage.js

One clue for what to look for is that there is a "use strict" directive, which is not a good idea for code intended to run in browsers that don't support strict mode. There doesn't seem to be any good reason to use it. I guess it's just hip.

There is some browser sniffing based on the UA string (not a good sign):

```
if($.browser.msie){
  // Stop IE from continually trying to preload images that we already removed
  document.execCommand("Stop", false);
}
```

Anyhow, the error seems to be related to code around line 226:

```
for(var j in $.Slides) {

  // Determine content (if container or image)
  if($.Slides[j].content.length == 0){
    c = '<img src="' + $.Slides[j].url + '" />';

  } else {
    c = $.Slides[j].content;
  }
  ...
}
```

So looking for where `Slides[j].content` is assigned a value, on line 625 there is:

```
  $.Slides = Utils.construct_slide_object();
```

and `construct_slide_object` is:

```
construct_slide_object: function() {
  var obj = new Object(),
      arr = new Array(),
      temp = '';

  $self.children().each(function(i) {
    var $img = $(this).is('img') ? $(this).clone() : $(this).find('img').first().clone();
```

Is that just a long way of writing `$('<img />')`?

```
    // reset obj
    obj = {};
```

So why initialise it as an object outside the `each` function?

```
    // set attributes to obj
    obj.url = $img.attr('src');
    obj.title = $img.attr('title') != undefined ? $img.attr('title') : '';
```

That's just a long way to write:

```
    obj.title = $img.attr('title');
```

since `attr` will always return a string, and `$img.attr('title') != undefined` is only true if it returned an empty string.

```
    obj.alt = $img.attr('alt') != undefined ? $img.attr('alt') : '';
    obj.theclass = $img.attr('class') != undefined ? $img.attr('class') : '';
    obj.styles = $img.attr('style') != undefined ? $img.attr('style') : '';
    obj.orig = $img.clone();
    obj.datahref = $img.attr('data-href') != undefined ? $img.attr('data-href') : '';
    obj.content = "";

    // Setup content for within container
    if ($(this).find('img').length > 0) {
```

That's the third time that's been used in this short bit of code.

```
      if($.BrowserTests.cssBackgroundSize) {
        $(this).find('img').first().remove();
```

And a fourth, `$(this)` is used 7 times.

```
      }
        obj.content = $(this).html();
      }

      // Stop loading image so we can load them sequentiallyelse{
      $img[0].src = "";

      // Remove original object (only on nonIE. IE hangs if you remove an image during load)
      if ($.BrowserTests.cssBackgroundSize) {
```

That seems to be some kind of browser inference: if the backgrounsize test returns false, it must be IE.

```
        $(this).remove();
      }

      // attach obj to arr
      arr.push(obj);
  });

  if(config.debug) { 
    debug(' - Slide Object - ');
    debug(arr);
  }
  return arr;
},
```

Fill yer boots. :-)

Comment: Hi, RobG, thx for your patience to explain the solution for me. It's very particular. But I tried it and failed. Here was what I did:

replace the primary code:

obj.title = $img.attr('title') != undefined ? $img.attr('title') : '';

to:
obj.title = $img.attr('title');


still shows the same errors on ie browsers.

plz tell me if I'm wrong. thank u. very appreciate!

Comment: That was just a comment on the code, I didn't expect it to have any effect. I suggest you run with the full version of the script and see what errors you get.